# What is the total sum of squares for these points?

Tags: regression, sums-of-squares

y = (-2,2,3,4) and x = (3,5,8,12). Lin. Model is y = -2.5 + 0.6x

Please explain how you got the answer. Thank you!

I am confused on whether I should be calculating based on the x or y values, or both?

Comment: Begin by looking up a definition of the term "sum of squares".

Comment: This can be answered by people here, based on our recognition of common notation conventions and common problems in early statistics education. But, as it is, this question is heavily under-specified and misleading based on the way you phrased it. In fact, the answer to the most discernible way to interpret your question is probably not the answer to the real question that you're looking for.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: I think the missing link is **fitted values**.

- From data $x$ and the line equation $y=-2.5+0.6x$, you should get **fitted value for all data points**. for example, the first fitted value is $-2.5+0.6\times(-2)=-3.7$
- From fitted value and response $y$, you should get residual
- From residual to sum of squares should be easy.